# Python Selenium - Extract text within <br>

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently looping through all labels and extracting data from each page, however I cannot extract the text highlighted below each category (i.e. **Founded, Location** etc..). The text appears to be within **" "** and above the **br** tags, can anyone advise how to extract please?

**Website -**
https://labelsbase.net/knee-deep-in-sound

```
                        <div class="line-title-block">
                            <div class="line-title-wrap">
                                <span class="line-title-text">Founded</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        2003
                        <br>


                        <div class="line-title-block">
                            <div class="line-title-wrap">
                                <span class="line-title-text">Location</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        
                        <a href="/?c=United+Kingdom">United Kingdom</a>
                        <br>
```

I have tried using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` & `driver.execute_script` but cannot find a solution.

**Error Message -**

```
Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rYQN.jpg)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import time
import string

PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
links = []
url = 'https://labelsbase.net/knee-deep-in-sound'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
# -- Title
title = driver.find_element_by_class_name('label-name').text
print(title,'\n')

# -- Image
image = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
src = image.get_attribute('src')
print(src,'\n')

# -- Founded
founded = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/text()[2]").text
print(founded,'\n')

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this

```
founded = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@*='block-content']").get_attribute("innerText")
```

You can take the XPath of the `class="block-content"`

**O/P**

[image]

Comment: Thanks yes this works but is there a way I can store each value separately? As I aim to store each value to be called upon later. 

i.e. I am iterating through every record label and want to save each record labels Location, Soundcloud followers, genres, image, name etc...